# SharePoint 2013 with Angular2 zone.js name conflict

Tags: angular, sharepoint-2013

I'm playing around with Angular2 RC6 and SharePoint 2013.

What had been working in RC5 no longer works.  Now it appears that **zone.js** and **SharePoint 2013** have a conflict with **global.Zone**.

By the time **zone.js** gets going, **SharePoint** has already made claim on **global.Zone** and **zone.js** reports *"Zone already loaded"*.

Has anyone else encountered this and gotten passed it?

Comment: I'm getting the same error in a straight angular 2 app... not using SharePoint at all.

Comment: I also have the same issue. Upgrading an rc.4 app to rc.6 led to "zone already loaded" error in SharePoint. It seems to be related to SharePoint as I can reproduce this error with the Angular-Seed app.

Comment: Zone.js people said they're not going to do anything as they say Microsoft shouldn't be polluting the global namespace.  Never mind this is new behavior they introduced.  

@FanLi had a good point about clearing out SharePoint's attachment to Zone as there have been no negative repercussions so far.

Answer (score 0):

Open `node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js`, comment out the line with `throw new Error('Zone already loaded.');` and build your project again. This works for the final version of Angular2.